# Want to document optional JSON parameters in Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have an API that I'm trying to document using Swagger.  My API takes a POJO as input via JSON in the RequestBody, and returns, likewise, a POJO as JSON in the ResponseBody.  Some of the fields in my JSON object are nullable, and others are required.  I would like my Swagger documentation to reflect which fields are nullable and which are required.  Is there a way to do this simply, without creating a Swagger config file which would likely be longer than manually documenting the API in a text editor?

As a concrete example, let's say I have a POJO that looks like this:

```
public class pojo {
    private String val1;
    private String val2;
    private String val3;
    //getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

Let's say I wanted my Swagger documentation to tell the reader: "On request, do not send val1 (e.g. this API is a database insert and val1 corresponds to the PK of the table which is supposed to be auto-generated), val2 is optional, and val3 is required".  How do I do this?

As a related question, how can I do something similar for the response body?  Like, using the POJO above, how can I say "on response, you should expect val1 to be empty, val2 might have a value or might be null, and val3 should have a value, assuming the service was successful"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to document optional parameters within your POJO object it is possible to use the [@ApiModelProperty](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apimodelproperty) attribute, for example:

```
public class pojo {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This parameter will be ignored", required = false)
    private String val1;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This parameter is optional", required = false)
    private String val2;
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private String val3;
    //getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

Swagger will take these annotations into account and it should be reflected in the documentation:

[image: Swagger UI]

And in yaml API documentation:

```
pojo:
    type: object
    required:
      - val3
    properties:
      val1:
        type: string
        description: This parameter will be ignored
      val2:
        type: string
        description: This parameter is optional
      val3:
        type: string
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and if it works I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: Sweet that worked.  Followup question, if you don't mind: What if I want to use the same POJO for multiple different APIs, and the required/optional status of various fields are dependent upon which API is using it?  Like say val1 is optional for API /endpoint1 but required for /endpoint2.

Comment: @Ertai87 I would recommend to ask this question separately. I cannot imagine any easy way to do it using the attributes. Probably I would prefer to duplicate the POJO object and change the attributes as needed, but maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: OK, I'll ask a separate question.  Thanks!